# OS X 10.9 homebrew requires Xcode.app's XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc after deleting the Xcode.app but leaving command line tools untouched

Tags: xcode, macos, homebrew

The error messages are:

==> Downloading https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/3.5.tar.gz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mod_wsgi/3.5 --disable-framework --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/a
==> make
./libtool --silent --mode=compile /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc    -DDARWIN -DSIGPROCMASK_SETS_THREAD_MASK -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/apache2  -I/usr/include/apr-1   -I/usr/include/apr-1  -g -O2 -arch x86_64 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DENABLE_DTRACE  -c -o mod_wsgi.lo mod_wsgi.c && touch mod_wsgi.slo
env: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc: No such file or directory
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1

Comment: Does `xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` work?

Comment: It was already `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` when `-p`. I also changed it, or `-r` reset it, but it still does not compile.